# Indy HTTP Proxy Server, how to set a password?

Tags: delphi, indy, proxy-server

I'm thinking of writing a Proxy Server. When I specify and activate the port using the `TIdHTTPProxyServer` component, the proxy server works properly. It's okay so far, but I can't password it and I can't open an IPv6 proxy. It's just an IPv4 proxy. I couldn't find much documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't password it

`TIdHTTPProxyServer` does not currently implement any authentication of its own.

HTTP authentication between the client and target server is handled transparently between the two of them, `TIdHTTPProxyServer` is not involved in that process.

If you want to password-protect the proxy itself, you will have to manually handle authentication in the proxy's `OnHTTPBeforeCommand` event.  Check the client's request headers (in the event's `AContext.Headers` property) for a `Proxy-Authorization` header, and if it is not present, or its credentials fail, then manually send the client (via the `AContext.Connection` property) an HTTP `407` response containing an appropriate `Proxy-Authenticate` header, and then `raise` an exception (or disconnect the `AContext.Connection`) to stop processing the current proxy request.

> I can't open an IPv6 proxy. It's just an IPv4 proxy.

`TIdHTTPProxyServer` can handle both IPv4 and IPv6, but it will require some manual setup.

Whichever IP version Indy is compiled for by default is specified in the global `ID_DEFAULT_IP_VERSION` constant in Indy's `IdGlobal` unit (it is set to IPv4, unless Indy is compiled with `IdIPv6` defined in `IdCompilerDefines.inc`).

Listening IP/port pairs can be configured in the proxy's `Bindings` collection. You can specify an `IPVersion` for each binding.  The `IPVersion` is set to `ID_DEFAULT_IP_VERSION` by default.

If you don't specify any `Bindings` entries, the proxy's `DefaultPort` property is used instead. The proxy will then open either 1 or 2 listening ports, depending on platform and OS capabilities. If 1 port is opened, it will use `ID_DEFAULT_IP_VERSION`. If 2 ports are opened, 1 will be IPv4 and 1 will be IPv6.

So, if you want control over the setup of the listening IP/ports, don't leave the `Bindings` empty.

Once a client has connected to a listening port, the `TIdHTTPProxyServerContext.OutboundClient` object that is used to connect to the next HTTP server will use `ID_DEFAULT_IP_VERSION` by default.  You can override this in the proxy's `OnHTTPBeforeCommand` event, by casting the event's `AContext.OutboundClient` property to `TIdTCPClient` and then setting its `IPVersion` property.

Comment: I made an experiment with the IPv6 code as follows.

Proxy_Server [ I ].Bindings.Items[0].IPVersion := TIdIPVersion.Id_IPv6;

Could you give an example of the password part?